# Google API Spread Sheet Pie Chart Data is not complete

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am using google spread sheet api to get spread sheet data and all charts data on spread sheet.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#read_chart_data

I successfully get all spreadsheet data but the chart data inside spreadsheet object is not complete.

For example here is my pie chart image on spread sheet.

[image]

And here is the response

[image]

In short I am not getting any label and its values data, or Is any way to get png/jpeg of chart from google spread sheet api.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: most charts have a `getImageURI` method, see --> [Printing PNG Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)

Comment: @WhiteHat, yeah you are right but all we need to get chart data from google spread sheet after that its easy to draw chart on my browser.

Comment: seems like the data for the chart would be in its own range somewhere in the spreadsheet -- shouldn't have to pull from the chart itself, maybe i don't follow, can you share an example spreadsheet?

Comment: @WhiteHat, thanks for the help. The api returns ranges(e.g startColumnIndex: 4 etc) but not actual data. So now first I got ranges and then hit api again passing range parameter and then I got actual data. :)